# Jura Water Filter, Decalcification and Reverse Osmosis

Tags: bean-to-cup, descaling, water

We use reverse osmosis water for our Jura S8 and don't use the Jura filter, because why when the water is pre-filtered.  Now the machine is telling us to decalcify the machine.

My question is, do I need to decalcify if I'm using reverse osmosis water?  Is it okay not to use a filter?  I want to take care of our machine, but I don't want to do pointless maintenance that isn't cheap.  TIA.